# Principal Component Analysis with correlated features and outliers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, pca

I am performing PCA on dataset of shape 300,1500 using scikit learn in Python 3. 
I have following questions in the context of PCA implementation in scikit learn and generally accepted approach.

1) Before doing PCA do I remove highly correlated columns? I have   67 columns which have correlation > 0.9. Does PCA automatically handle this correlation I.e ignores them?

2) Do I need to remove outliers before performing PCA?

3) if I have to remove outliers how best to approach this. Using z-score for each column when I tried to remove outliers (z-score >3) I am left with only 15 observations. It seems like wrong approach.

4) Finally is there ideal amount of cumulative explained variance which I should be using to choose P components. In this case around 150 components give me 90% cum explained variance

Comment: Might be better suiter to [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @srinivas-suresh   Can I transfer this question to data Science or cross validated?

Comment: Yes, flag the question and wait for a mod

Answer (score 1):

With regards to using PCA, PCA will discover the axes of greatest variance in your data. Consequently:

1. No, you no not need to remove correlated features.
2. You shouldn't need to remove outliers for any a priori reason related to PCA. That said, if you think they are potentially manipulating your results either for analysis or prediction you could consider removing them, although I don't think they are a problem for PCA per se.
3. That is probably not the right approach. First things first visualize your data and look for your outliers. Also, I wouldn't assume the distribution of your data and apply a basic z score to it. Some googling on criteria on removing outliers would be useful here.
4. There are various cutoffs people use with PCA. 99% can be quite common, although I don't know if there is a hard and fast rule. If your goal is prediction, there there will probably be a trade off between speed and the accuracy of your predictions. You will need to find the cutoff that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else lands here without having seen the answer about correlated columns on [statsexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50537/should-one-remove-highly-correlated-variables-before-doing-pca)

I thoroughly recommend reading the anwers, but as a tl;dr, here's the conclusion:

> We can see now that there may be merit in discarding variables thought to be measuring the same underlying (but "latent") aspect of a collection of variables, because including the nearly-redundant variables can cause the PCA to overemphasize their contribution.

> There is nothing mathematically right (or wrong) about such a procedure; it's a judgment call based on the analytical objectives and knowledge of the data. But it should be abundantly clear that setting aside variables known to be strongly correlated with others can have a substantial effect on the PCA results.